# What should I do about overly aggressive comments from a user?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

I'm not sure whether to flag comments from a user or not. This user has asked for the traditional Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, which is fair enough.

However the attitude surrounding them is pretty...I'm not sure what the word is. But I don't like it, particularly illustrated by the quotes:

> TRY, TRY, TRY...

and

> I also request to try on the lastest [sic] version since I do not want to spend time investigating something that might already be solved in a recent version

Are these considered flaggable or not? I'm trying to get a feel for where the boundary lies. They rub me up the wrong way, but does it cross the line into unfriendly? I'm not certain.

Comment: Do you find it offensive? no longer needed? unkind? flag it. if you're unsure.... it probably isn't any of those things.

Comment: The worst that could happen is that your flag gets declined. And while you can get banned from flagging for a while I don't think permanent flag bans are a thing. But if you really want to be safe, if a comment you're not sure is unfriendly enough to qualify for that flag can be considered 'no longer needed' then use that flag instead. That flag doesn't carry a penalty for the user who makes the comment so you don't have to worry about someone declining it for the comment not being bad enough.

Comment: I suppose I can also take the view that if I'm not sure, someone else might be.

Comment: *Slightly* more context would be nice, although seeing all CAPS in a comment doesn't bode well for "kindness".

Comment: You're really cherry-picking your quotations here, IMO. Those comments are composed primarily of what appears to be useful information.

Comment: @Makoto - check history of this post for context - in my opinion the only questionable word is "request"... (and not disengaging after first comment). The author of the comments actually tried to be helpful with guidance...also comments are very generic and can be handled the same "unkind" way as all other http://idownvotedbecau.se/

Comment: That second excerpt just seems like someone who doesn't quite know the nuances of written English, not necessarily rude.

Comment: I'm sorely disappointed that this wasn't about me.

Comment: @squaregoldfish: I find it disconcerting that you seem to have posted only *fragments* of the comment, rather than the comment as a whole. These sorts of things are defined as much by context as anything else.

Comment: I originally posted links to the questions for context, but they've been edited out (apparently that's not good - fair enough). The consensus immediately after posting was that it was a bad question. I was going to delete but now I'm not allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

I **don't** believe the commenter was aggressive, but condescending.

To me the commenter kind looked like silly by **insisting** saying he would not waste his time looking at the question because the version was old, as if OP or someone else had specifically asked him to do so, even **after** OP genuinely explained he could not upgrade.

I would say flag such comments under the 'unfriendly or unkind' reason.

Aside from that, I think he tried to help: suggested to upgrade software (before OP said he could not), required a reproducible example (which is mandatory), and shared technical advice. You should also weight this side of the interaction as a trade off for getting good answers.

Comment: I chuckle at the silly people who waste their time saying that they won't waste their time.

Answer (score -2):

*Neither* of these comments are doing us any favors.

Let's look at this one:

[image]

> I have not looked in detail The reason being that if there is no Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example it might be harder to understand or confusinge and I only start really loking into things if there is an Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, But even then, PF 6.2 is already out for some time and 7.0RC3 is available, so if there is an Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example I also request to try on the lastest version since I do not want to spend time investigating something that might already be solved in a recent version

So, effectively what I got from this comment:

- I'm not going to help you until you put together an MCVE
- This is fixed in another version
- I don't *want* to help you if it's fixed in another version

...which doesn't sound helpful *at all*.  The good faith intended by asking the OP to add more details to their question is destroyed by their delivery.

What a shame.

---

The second comment is more exasperation and falls into the same pattern.

[image]

> TRY..... I'm not going to spend time searching for problems that are known to be fixed in newer versions. And if they are, the source is open and you can try to backport fixes
>
> TRY for a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.... TRY, TRY, TRY, I'm not stating you shoud use it in production... And did you read my last comment? stackoverflow.com/questions/13175512/…

Okay, I get it, you can get impatient with someone, but there are two problems with this:

- We have the "I don't want to help you" mentality unless the OP updates (and they may not be able to)
- The message of "please include what you've actually done and what you're seeing so we could be of any value to you" is destroyed once again by its delivery.

---

So honestly, I'd flag them as "No longer needed".  They're not exactly rude in my mind (although the second chain ventures closer to it than the first), but they're *definitely* not necessary.

Comment: I don't agree with your characterization of the first comment. While it is biased towards what the user themselves prefer, the kinds of questions that need an MCVE still need one, so letting them know about that is not unreasonable. And the person never claims that it certainly has been fixed, only that it might have been fixed, so the OP should check. Which is also very reasonable.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  Honestly, the first comment reads like the person wants to kite the question.  No one *cares* if they don't answer questions if the question lacks an MCVE, and no one *cares* if they don't want to spend time investigating the problem.  Those statements far outweigh the request to actually produce the MCVE in the first place, to me.